# Swift Xcode 6 If Else statement check letters or numbers

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to write and if else statement.

I need it to check if `atextField` is empty or has letters and if the `textfield` is empty or has letters is triggers a `UIAlertWIndow`.

I have tried boolean methods to no avail.

Any ideas?

This is what I have written so far:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if self.numOfGuestsData.text == ""  {
        alert()
        println("Something Amish")

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Split The Bill", message:
            "Please Enter The Number of Guests!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if self.numOfGuestsData.text != "" {
        let subTotalVC = segue.destinationViewController as subTotalAmountViewController

        subTotalVC.numOfGuests = numOfGuestsData.text
        println("everything is Ok Here")
    }
}
```

Also if I take out the alert window the if else statement fails for some reason.

Like if I write it like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if self.numOfGuestsData.text == ""  {
        alert()
        println("Something Amish")

    } else if self.numOfGuestsData.text != "" {
        let subTotalVC = segue.destinationViewController as subTotalAmountViewController

        subTotalVC.numOfGuests = numOfGuestsData.text
        println("everything is Ok Here")
    }
}
```

It just goes to the else...

Comment: instead of checking if a string equals "" why not use if countElements(myString) == 0

Comment: I never knew about that =P I will give it a shot now!

Comment: won't fix your problem just a good practice to adhere to :)

Comment: Definitely, its a better logic than asking if it is blank. =P

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to suppress the segue if the textField is empty and present a UIAlertController instead if that is the case? Are you using a show segue? I think your logic needs to be moved out of `prepareForSegue:` and moved into `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:`. Do your check in that method. Doing the logic in `prepareForSegue:` is too late; the segue is definitely going to happen by then.

Basically, you'll override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` and then either `return true` or `return false` based on your logic. If it returns false, the segue won't happen.

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:).

Comment: Yes correct! Ah I didnt know about that shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @JoeCRONEScrivens don't forget to make trevorj's answer correct if it worked for you. Just tick the green button.

Comment: @JoeCRONEScrivens Great to hear! :) If it works for you, please feel free to "accept" my answer like CeceXX said.